# How do I stop Pandas from continuing to put the same data on the same plot?

Tags: python, pandas

My first post, so I hope I do this correctly!

This is admittedly an OOP modification of something on DataCamp.  I have two objects which contain Pandas dataframes.  The first (StockData) has stock data for every trading day of 2016 for both Amazon and Facebook.  The second (BenchmarkData) has the S&P 500 closing values for every trading day of 2016.  For both, I want to calculate the percent change (StockReturns and BenchmarkReturns, respectively) and then plot them.  I want both of the StockReturns on the same plot, but the BenchmarkReturns (which is a Series and not a dataframe for reasons irrelevant to this part of the code) on a separate plot.  For my function, I've added a flag as input to tell the program whether the object contains a stock dataframe or a benchmark dataframe and I call the function twice during runtime, once for stock and the other for benchmark.  However, no matter what I do, Pandas plots all 3 on the same plot.  How do I separate the benchmark data and get it on its own plot?

```
    def _CalculatePercentChange(self, IsStockData):
        
        if(IsStockData):
            self.__StockReturns = self.__StockData.GetData().pct_change()
            self.__StockReturns.plot(title = 'Daily Percent Change')
        
        else:
            self.__BenchmarkReturnsDataFrame = self.__BenchmarkData.GetData().pct_change()
            self.__BenchmarkReturns = self.__BenchmarkReturnsDataFrame['S&P 500'].squeeze()
            self.__BenchmarkReturns.plot(title = 'Daily Percent Change')
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with some more of `matplotlib`. Here's a relevant section of the docs: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html#stacking-subplots-in-one-direction and with `pandas` you would instead pass the different axes to the `ax` keyword argument of `df.plot()` e.g.: `df1.plot(ax=axes[0]); df2.plot(ax=axes[1])`.

Comment: Ok, great, thanks!  That fixed things.